# Put an id inside CSS media query

Tags: css, media-queries

How to add a **Tag** or **id** inside the CSS media-query as below.

```
@media only screen (#id {attribute:value}){
#id2{
display:flex
}
```

Comment: What do you want to solve with that media query?  Under which condition `#id2{
display:flex
}` be applied? (what should `#id {attribute:value}` do?)

Comment: Hi, it's possible you are misunderstanding media queries which are for, well, querying the medium that the code is being run on, I don't understand what you want to happen with #id {attribute:value} could you describe some more? See [link]https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/419681/screenshots/4803219/customers_page.gif

Comment: @AHaworth media queries are about asking things about the environment in which the rendering takes place. Like width/height of the viewport, if it is an environment with mouse or touch input, about accessibility settings like reduced motion, preferred color theme, if scripting is active, light level, … . And there is also a draft to not only query for the size of the viewport but also about the size of a container element in which another element is in (_Container-Queries_).

Comment: @t.niese - agreed - but I still don't understand what is supposed to happen with #id {attribute:value} in the question, it doesn't seem to be about the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Update your CSS

```
@media only screen{ #id2[attribute:value]{ display:flex }}
```

Comment: @NitinBansal this comment does not clarify in anyway what you want to do.

Comment: I want this
@media only screen and (div {width:50%}) {
p
{
display:none;
}
}

Comment: @NitinBansal add this information to your question and explain exactly what it should do. And it is still not clear what `div {width:50%}` should query for.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple.

```
@media only screen{
    TagName{
      display:flex;
    }
    #id {
      AttributeName: value;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I want this
@media only screen and (#id{property:value){ 
#id2[attribute:value]{ 
display:flex 
}